# Component is not re rendering after state change in react

Tags: reactjs

While working on my project I faced this issue and tried for two days to solve it. Finally I decided to post it here. 
I am rendering array by calling child component as follows:-
**Parent component**

```
{this.state.list.map((item,index)=>{
    return <RenderList 
        insert={this.insert.bind(this,index)}
        index={index}
        length={this.state.list.length}
        EnterPressed={this.childEnterPressed.bind(this,index)} 
        list={item} 
        onchange={this.childChange.bind(this)} 
        editable={this.state.editable[index]} 
        key={index} 
        onclick={this.tagClicked.bind(this,index)} />
})}
```

and

**Child component**

```
<Draggable grid={[37, 37]} 
            onStop={this.handleDrop.bind(this)} 
            axis="y" 
            onDrag={this.handleDrag.bind(this)} 
            bounds={{top: -100, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 100}}
>
    <div onClick={this.tagClicked.bind(this)}>
        { this.props.editable ? (<Input 
                                        type="text"
                                        label="Edit Item"
                                        id="listItem"
                                        name="listItem"
                                        onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress.bind(this)}
                                        defaultValue={this.props.list}
                                        onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />) : 
                                    (<Chip>{this.props.list}</Chip>) }
        </div>
</Draggable>
```

I am using react-draggble to make each individual item of my list draggble. When ot is dragged in **handleDrag** function I am just updating my state of distance by which component is draged and in **handleDrop** function I am calling insert function which delete the dragged item from its current position and insert at position where it is dropped.

```
insert=function(index,y,e){
    if(y!==0){
        var list=this.state.list;
        var editable = Array(this.state.editable.length).fill(false);
        if(y/37>0){
            var temp=list[index];
            var i=0;
            for(i=index;i<index+y/37;i++){
                list[i]=this.state.list[i+1];
            }
            list[(y/37)+index]=temp;
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                list:list,
                editable:editable
            })
        }
    }
```

State is updating correctly. I have tested it but component is not re rendering. what surprised me is that if I just display the list in the same component then it re render correctly.any help is appreciated!

Comment: I guess React cannot keep track of the items, as your are using the `index` as `key` (which is discouraged). Try to create a unique `key` based on something unique which sticks to the item.

Comment: @lipp thank that works correctly by providing unique key to each item instead of index. But I don't understand why index as key is not working because index is also unique to each item in the list. Can you explain this.Thank You again. Really, it is great help to me.

Comment: made it an answer. hope this helps. have to leave... can go into more detail later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React cannot keep track of the items, as your are using the index as key (which is [discouraged](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)). Try to create a unique key based on something like a generated uuid which sticks to the item.

When dragging an item, the position (index) in the array changes. This prevents React from syncing the correct elements. Prop/state changes may not propagate as wanted.